# How to store dynamic multiple array state react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How to store dinamic multiple input form to array at ES6? This is what i tried, but cannot work.

this is my state

```
state = {
  person: 9
  personInfo: []
}
```

this is my looping array and map code

```
let dataVisaPerson = []
      for (let person = 1; person <= this.state.person; person++) {
        dataVisaPerson.push({key: person, value: person, text: person + ' Persons'})
      }

    const PassportData = dataVisaPerson.map(PassportDataInfo => { return (
       <Form as={Segment} key={PassportDataInfo.key} loading={this.state.isLoading}>
         <h5>Person {PassportDataInfo.value}</h5> 
         <Form.Group widths="equal">
           <Form.Input value={this.state.personInfo[PassportDataInfo.value].number} onChange={e =>  {const number = this.state.personInfo; number[PassportDataInfo.value].number = e.target.value;}} />
           <Form.Input value={this.state.personInfo[PassportDataInfo.value].created} onChange={e => {const created = this.state.personInfo; created[PassportDataInfo.value].created = e.target.value;}} />
           <Form.Input value={this.state.personInfo[PassportDataInfo.value].expired} onChange={e => {const expired = this.state.personInfo; expired[PassportDataInfo.value].expired = e.target.value;}} />
         </Form.Group>
       </Form>

    return ({PassportData})
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you check your console for errors?

Comment: i just got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `setState` to update your component state. Never mutate it directly.

In your case your will need to create a new version of the array with the updated values, something in the line of:

```
updatePerson = (value, index) => {
    this.setState({
        personInfo: [...this.state.personInfo].splice(index, 1, value)
    }) 
}
```